# Excel Vlookup calculating grades with mark range

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am new to excel and i would like to use a function called vlookup to calculate some grades according to a table.
However i failed to do so which i do not know where i did wrong in the formula. 
can anyone point me out to a solution please? Thank you so much~

The link below will be the image of my the excel.
http://postimg.org/image/n26gxaxpx/

Comment: When using `TRUE` as the *range_lookup* parameter, the values in the first column of the *table_array* must be sorted in *ascending order*. You will have to reverse the order or use `INDEX(MATCH(...))` as `MATCH` can locate in a descending order. [VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010069835.aspx).

Comment: I missed it the first time but the *Marks* for **B** might also be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by Jeeped in his comment, in case you are using TRUE instead of FALSE in VLOOKUP range parameter, you need to sort in ascending order the first column of the table.

Besides using VLOOKUP, or INDEX(MATCH(...)) that in my opinion is much more powerful, I would like to suggest a different strategy for your needs. After you have ordered your reference table, in fact you may use easily a series of IF functions like this:

```
=IF(J2 < 100, IF(J2 < 80, IF(J2 < 60, IF(J2 < 20, "E", "D"), "C"), "B"), "A")
```

In case you prefer to use a table with key values that you can easily vary depending on your needs, you may replace numbers and texts with references (and in such case if you are pasting this formula in different cells, remind to block the references, i.e. put the $ signs). For instance you could have:

```
=IF(J2 < $G$13, IF(J2 < $G$14, IF(.....), $H$14), $H$13)
```